# Sending a JSON file with multiple JSON objects through KAFKA

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a file which contains multiple json documents in the following format.

`{"attribute1": "value1", "attribute2": "value2", "attribute3": "value3",  "attribute4": "value4"}
{"attribute1": "value11", "attribute2": "value12", "attribute3": "value13",  "attribute4": "value14"}
{"attribute1": "value21", "attribute22": "value2", "attribute23": "value3",  "attribute4": "value24"}`

I am trying to send the individual json documents to kafka. 
The script executes with an exit code 0 but I can see no messages coming through on the KAFKA consumer. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import csv
import json

bootstrap = ['hostname:9092']
valueSerializer = lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8')

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = bootstrap, value_serializer = valueSerializer)

table = []
with open('~/json_file_name.json', 'r') as json_file:
    for line in json_file:
        table.append(json.loads(line))

#numrows = len(table)
#print(numrows)

for row in table:
    print(row)
    producer.send('Topic_Name', value=row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you're not sending enough data for the producer to flush its batch. You've not shown your import for the KafkaProducer, but see if you can do `producer.flush()` at the end of the script

---

You don't need a table variable, by the way, just send while you read the file lines. You also don't need to `dumps(x)` since you are sending strings obtained by `json.loads` already

You can also remove the csv import

Comment: I added producer.flush() at the end of the script and the data was sent to Kafka